# I need help fixing my code to not take items from a room twice

Tags: python

I have finished my text game and made some modifications but now when i finih the game and go to the nursery to defeat the baby,(lol), it adds the baby to the inventory and ends the game. I need to make it so that when the player gets to the nursery with all seven items the player wins the game.

```
rooms = {
'playroom': {'east': 'living room'},
'living room': {'north': 'kitchen', 'east': 'bathroom', 'south': 'library', 'west': 'nursery'},
'kitchen': {'west': 'garage', 'east': 'pantry', 'south': 'living room'},
'garage': {'east': 'kitchen'},
'pantry': {'west': 'kitchen'},
'bathroom': {'north': 'laundry room', 'west': 'living room'},
'laundry room': {'south': 'bathroom'},
'library': {'north': 'living room'},
'nursery': {'east': 'living room'}
    }
item = {
'living room': 'pacifier',
'kitchen': 'milk',
'garage': 'diaper',
'pantry': 'bottle',
'bathroom': 'wipes',
'laundry room': 'blankie',
'library': 'book',
'nursery': 'baby',
   }

print('Get the Baby to Sleep Adventure Game')
print('Collect the 7 items to win or deal with a cranky baby')
print('Move Commands: south, east, west, north')
print("Add to Inventory: Get 'item name' \n")

start = 'playroom' ## you start in the playroom
inventory = []


def get_new_start(start, direction): ## function
    new_start = start ## declaring a new start position
    for i in rooms:
        if i == start:
            if direction in rooms[i]:
                new_start = rooms[i][direction] ## assigning a new start

    return new_start



while (True):  ## loop for game to play
    print('The room you are in is the', start)
    print('Your inventory includes',inventory)
    direction = input('Enter which way you want to go or enter exit: ')
    if (direction == 'exit'):
        print('Thanks for playing, BYE!!!!')
        exit(0)

    if (direction == 'south' or direction == 'north' or direction == 'east' or direction == 'west'):
        new_start = get_new_start(start, direction)
        if new_start == start:
            print('You cannot go that direction, please enter another direction.')
        else:
            start = new_start
    else:
        print('Invalid Direction.')

    if start in item.keys() and item[start] != None and item[start] not in inventory and item[start] != 'nursery':
        print('The item in this room is', item[start])
        inventory.append(item[start])

    if start in item.keys() and item[start] == 'baby':
        if len(inventory) == 7:
            print('Yay, you have all the items and you put the baby to sleep, enjoy some time to yourself')
        else:
            print('You have lost the game. Please try again. GAME OVER')

        exit(0)
```

Comment: We need _way_ more info than this.  StackOverflow is not a forum, per se, we are a Q&A site.  In order for a question to be answered, you should try to provide as much info as you can so we can help.  You don't need to post the entire program, but just a small example that shows the issue you are having.

Comment: You're going to need to show a lot more information if you want help. Code, debugging that you've done, etc.

Comment: You can just simply check if the item is already in `inventory` before calling `inventory.append()` (and printing "the item in this room").  This may be easier than the alternative of _removing_ the item from the room after getting it, so if you go in the room again, there's nothing there (and then you don't call `inventory.append()`).

Comment: I have revised my question. This is my first time time using stack overflow so I apologize for my initial post.

Comment: should i use an if statement for that?

Comment: @MichelleVebber Yes, an `if` to check whether the item is _already_ in `inventory` is the simplest solution.  Or rather, check `if` the item is not in `inventory` and if it's not then you can `.append()` it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I dont know what to put in my else<br/>     if start in item.keys() and item[start] != None and item[start] != 'nursery':
        print('The item in this room is', item[start])
        if item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(item[start])
        else:

Comment: What `else`?  What do you mean?  You don't need an `else`.  You either add the item to `inventory` or you do nothing.

Comment: I took your suggestion and fixed that problem but now when I reach the nursery with all seven items it ends the game instead of saying the player won

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply add another clause to your `if` before adding the item.

Check `item[start] not in inventory` before you add the item.

```
if start in item.keys() and item[start] != None and item[start] not in inventory and item[start] != 'baby':
```